# CWAC EndlessAdapter Android

Tags: android, listview

Anyone could tell me how to use CWAC EndlessAdapter library with JSON ? Or suggest me  a link of a tutorial? I have a file from txt in dropbox and I have already use JSON to get it in to the LISTVIEW but it take time to load all so I want to load only 10 first and then 10 for next until end. Base on my research i have found EnlessAdapter but I don't know how to use it https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless. Can anyone tell me about it or using other way but the same result ? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Quoting the project `README`: "**THIS PROJECT IS RETIRED**".

Comment: How are you parsing the json into the listview currently?

Comment: ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), contactList,
     R.layout.listsingleitem, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
       TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_CityProvince, TAG_Country,
       TAG_PHONE_OFFICE, TAG_Fax, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_Site },
     new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.addresst, R.id.CPt,
       R.id.countryt, R.id.phonet, R.id.faxt, R.id.emailt,
       R.id.sitet });

   lv.setAdapter(adapter);